# Remove img in html that non contain src attribute

Tags: php, html, regex, dom, preg-replace

I need remove all img element in html that non contain src attribute with preg_match and PHP

something like:

```
<html>
 <img src="someurl" alt="something"  />
 <img  alt="something"  />
<html />
```

in

```
<html>
 <img src="someurl" alt="something"  />
<html />
```

Tanks

Comment: don't use regex. use dom+xpath...

Comment: Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: In this project I can't use DOM Parser

Comment: See ["You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex ..."](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2257664).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case your boss insists on a regex, and (s)he does not hear to the voice of wisdom, you can try the following regex:

```
(?si)\s*<img\b(?>(?!src=).)*?\/>\s*
```

See [demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kC9uB6/1).

Sample PHP code:

```
$re = "/(?si)\\s*<img\\b(?>(?!src=).)*?\\/>\\s*/"; 
$str = "<html>\n <img src=\"someurl\" alt=\"something\"  />\n <img  alt=\"something\"  />\n <img  alt=\"somethingelse\"\n       att='val'  />\n<html />"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, "", $str);
```